# Java Вопрос по файлам и чтению их в массивы

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, scanner

Простите, если путанно и многословно объясняю...

Есть три файла. Содержания примерно такого:

Файл1:

> бла1
>   бла2
>    бла3

Файл2:

> бла0
>   бла8
>   бла1
>   бла17
>   бла2
>   бла6

Файл3:

> блаблабла
>   бла бла
>   бла бла бла
>   бла
>   блабла
>   бла бла

То есть, как видно, некоторые (не все) строки из `файла1` входят в `файл2`, а кол-во строк *файла2 = кол-ву строк файла3*

Задача: найти номера тех строк в файле2, которые совпадают со строками файла1 и записать в файл4 (новый) строки содержания "<искомая строка> + <строка из файла3 с номером равным номеру искомой строки в файле2>

Ну, например (исходя из моего примера). Находим, что бла1 входит в третьей строке файла2, а бла2 в пятой строке. Значит, в файле4 запишем следующее: бла1 бла бла бла \n бла2 блабла

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил...

Я решил, что проще всего загнать все файлы в три разных массива и массивы уже сравнивать.

В чем проблема: массивы обнуляются сразу после цикла чтения файла. Примеры кода:

```
File cena = new File("cena.txt");
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(cena);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String line = null;

String[] cena_array;
cena_array = new String[1000];

int cena_n = 0;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    cena_n++;
    cena_array[cena_n] = line;
    System.out.println(cena_array[cena_n]); // Здесь выводит нормально элемент массива
}
System.out.println(cena_array[1]); // а здесь уже null, как и cena_n
```

Пробовал также через сканнер:

```
Scanner cena = new Scanner(new File("cena.txt"));
String[] cena_array;
cena_array = new String[1000];
int cena_n = 0;
while(cena.hasNext()){
    cena_n++;
    cena_array[cena_n] = cena.nextLine();
    System.out.println(cena_array[cena_n]); // Здесь снова нормально выводит элементы
}
System.out.println(cena_array[2]); // Ну, а здесь null
```

Пробовал обойтись одними файлами, написал вот такую лабуду:

```
String s = "";


Scanner cena = new Scanner(new File("cena.txt"));
FileWriter wrt;
wrt = new FileWriter("res.txt");
String[] cena_array;
cena_array = new String[1000];
int n = 0;
int k = 0;

while(cena.hasNext()){
    s = cena.nextLine();
    Scanner ost = new Scanner(new File("ost.txt"));
    boolean fl = true;
    n = 0;
    while ((ost.hasNext()&&(fl))){
      n++;
      if (s.equals(ost.hasNext())){
        fl = false;
        System.out.println("Нашли строку");
      } 
    }
    System.out.println("Вышли из while");
    if (!fl){
        Scanner ost_ost = new Scanner(new File("ost_ost.txt"));
        k = 1;
        while (k < n){
            ost_ost.hasNext();
        }
        wrt.append(s+" "+ost_ost.hasNext()+"\n");
        ost_ost.close();
        System.out.println("Записали в файл");
    }
```

В этом случае, программа выполняется бесконечно, не доходит до `System.out.println("Нашли строку");` и до конца первого файла. Ну, это дурацкий вариант, конечно

Подскажите, что сделать в первых двух вариантах, чтобы массивы не обнулялись по выходу из цикла?

Comment: ну или как сделать по другому

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("result.txt"))) {
    Files
        //построчно считываем первый файл
        .lines(Paths.get("first.txt"))
        .map(line -> {
               try {
                  //построчно считываем второй файл
                  return Files
                            .lines(Paths.get("second.txt"))
                            //добавляем информацию о номере строки
                            .map(
                               new Function<String, Entry<Integer, String>>() {
                                   private AtomicInteger lineNumber = new AtomicInteger();

                                   @Override
                                   public Entry<Integer, String> apply(String line) {
                                        return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(lineNumber.getAndIncrement(), line);
                                   }
                                })
                            //ищем совпадение со строкой из первого файла
                            .filter(entry -> line.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue()))
                            .findFirst();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                })
          //фильтруем строки для которых нашлось совпадение
          .filter(Optional::isPresent)
          .map(Optional::get)
          .map(entry -> {
               try {
                  return Files
                          //читаем третий файл
                          .lines(Paths.get("third.txt"))
                          //получем n строку, где n номер строки найденой во втором файле
                          .skip(entry.getKey())
                          .findFirst()
                          //объединяем полученную строку со строкой из второго файла
                          .map(e -> e + entry.getValue())
                          .get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           })
           //записываем результат
           .forEach(line -> {
                try {
                    writer.write(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Я бы для начала прочитал первый файл в какой-нибудь `TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`, чтобы не перечитывать второй файл так часто.

Comment: @vp_arth а если файл будет очень большим? Лучше пусть медленнее, но гарантировано отработает, чем свалится на outofmemory.

Comment: Тоже верно, it depends, как говорится

Answer (score 1):

Если файлы влезают в память, то самое простое решение будет вычитать их целиком:

```
void processFiles(Path file1, Path file2, Path file3, Path outputFile) throws IOException {
    // Первый файл читаем в Set, чтобы ыбстро искать
    Set<String> lines1 = new HashSet<>(Files.readAllLines(file1));
    // Второй файл в List, чтобы сохранить номера строк
    List<String> lines2 = Files.readAllLines(file2);
    // Ищем номера строк из второго файла, которые есть в первом
    int[] lineNumbers = IntStream.range(0, lines2.size())
                                 .filter(idx -> lines1.contains(lines2.get(idx)))
                                 .toArray();
    // Читаем третий файл - тоже в List, чтобы номера строк сохранить
    List<String> lines3 = Files.readAllLines(file3);
    // Генерируем результат, начиная с найденных номеров строк
    List<String> result = Arrays.stream(lineNumbers)
                                .mapToObj(idx -> lines2.get(idx) + " " + lines3.get(idx))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Записываем результат
    Files.write(outputFile, result);
}
```